# What's the right preposition to use with the verb "enroll"?

Tags: prepositions

The dictionary says that one enrolls in a university, but today I heard a person saying

> "The student enrolled at the school."

Is it right? Can I use both the prepositions "in" and "at"?

Comment: [Take your pick](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=enroll+at+college%2Cenroll+at+the+college%2Cenroll+in+college%2Cenroll+in+the+college&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cenroll%20at%20the%20college%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cenroll%20in%20college%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cenroll%20in%20the%20college%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I generally hear *enrol **at** an institution*, *enrol **in** or **on** a programme or course*, and if you are the mouthpiece of the institution, I hear *enrol **with** us*.

Here's [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/enrol):

> **Enrol**
>
> VERB [INTRANSITIVE/TRANSITIVE] British English pronunciation: enrol /ɪnˈrəʊl/
>
> if you enrol at a school or other institution, or if someone enrols
> you there, you put your name on the official list of its students or
> members
>
> **enrol at**: *Andrew cannot enrol at his local school because the class is full.*
>
> **enrol someone in/on something**: *Isabelle enrolled her brother in a training programme for engineers.*

Comment: Might be worth noting that *enrol* is the British spelling, while *enroll* is the American.

Comment: Yes, should have mentioned this. BrE _enrol, enrolment_; AmE _enroll, enrollment_; both BrE and AmE _enrolled, enrolling_.

Answer (score 5):

From [Cambridge Dictionary Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/enrol) :

Enroll **at** an institution

Enroll **in/on/for** a course/department

Enroll **with** someone

Answer (score 2):

Enroll  at (a/an) = college, institute, university, name + school + at + the + school.

Enroll in  (a/an) = college, program, course, school, class, exchange program, choir, academy.

"Enrol on" is a British term for enroll in.

Enroll for (a/an) = check,  vacancy, course, semester.

Answer (score 1):

The TLTR version is that if you want to be on the safe side, always use the verb with the preposition **in**.

It can also be used with the other two prepositions but they're not as frequent as the former - a word of caution is that the combination with the preposition **on** is more common in British English.

Hope that is of help